# Connector returning 1000 internal server error on pushing message to UE. How to solve the issue in connector?

Tags: unificationengine

Getting 1000 internal server error from connector on pushing message to UE.

How to solve the connector issue ?

The error message is

> { status: 1000, info: '1000 Internal Error' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uri parameter provided in "push/notification" request may be wrong.
It should be connectorscheme://connectionname@appid/channelname.